# Deserialization error from RESTful API

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting an error saying

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path ', line 0, position 0.

when try to parse JSON response (not entire, but first few items, I changed in the xxxxxx's for anonymity):

```
{
  "total_count": 1091,
  "items": [
    {
      "hap": "retry_limit_reached",
      "message": "Retry limit reached. Dropped: postmaster@xxxxx.ca \u2192 hamnifold@cxxxxxxxxems.com 'REMINDER - Pattison Stampede BBQ (Jul 11, 2018)' No MX for crscranessystems.com Server response: 498 No MX for crscranessystems.com",
      "type": "error",
      "created_at": "Thu, 05 Jul 2018 06:45:48 GMT",
      "message_id": "20180704185046.1.F263522F7F8571FE@mxxxxxx.ca"
    },
    {
      "hap": "tempfailed",
      "message": "Will retry in 14400 seconds: postmaster@xxxxxxxx.ca \u2192 conor@xxxxxxxxxy.org 'REMINDER - Pattison Stampede BBQ (Jul 11, 2018)' No MX for greexxxxxxxy.org Server response: 498 No MX for grexxxxxxy.org",
      "type": "warn",
      "created_at": "Thu, 05 Jul 2018 06:45:17 GMT",
      "message_id": "20180704225015.1.E917B878FC275EE7@mxxxxxxx.ca"
    },
    {
      "hap": "opened",
      "message": "Opened: jordan@lixxxxxxxxs.com",
      "type": "info",
      "created_at": "Thu, 05 Jul 2018 06:45:15 GMT",
      "message_id": "20180704192612.1.856579D071F84CF8@xxxxxxx.ca"
    },
    {
      "hap": "tempfailed",
      "message": "Will retry in 14400 seconds: postmaster@mxxxxxxx.ca \u2192 ccrawford@xxxxxx.com 'SUBJECT' No MX for step-eps.com Server response: 498 No MX for stxxxxxx.com",
      "type": "warn",
      "created_at": "Thu, 05 Jul 2018 06:45:14 GMT",
      "message_id": "20180704225014.1.33D047AC8A685236@xxxxxxxxi.ca"
    },
    //...
```

Here is part of my code:

```
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ViewBag.Msg = "Success";
    var stresult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
    var flogs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailLog>>(stresult);
    logs = flogs.ToList();
}
```

Here is the emaillog model:

```
public class EmailLog
{
    public string hap { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public string created_at { get; set; }

    public string message_id { get; set; }
}
```

This is the first time I have ever used RESTful API and JSON, so I might be missing something easy.

EDIT:

This is my full controller code which makes the API request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@api.mailgun.net/v3");

            List<EmailLog> logs = new List<EmailLog>();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/mg.xxxxx.ca/log");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                //    var stresult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
                //    var flogs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailLog>>(stresult);
                //    logs = flogs.ToList();
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
                if (jObject.ContainsKey("items"))
                {
                    ViewBag.Msg = "Success";
                    logs = jObject["items"].ToObject<List<EmailLog>>();
                }
                //var logs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);

            }

            else { ViewBag.Msg = "Fail"; }

            return View(logs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to creating a root object as already explained in another answer

This approach takes advantage of  the Linq To JSON provided by the Json.Net, which is being used to deserialize the JSON.

```
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    ViewBag.Msg = "Success";
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    if (jObject.ContainsKey("items"))
        logs = jObject["items"].ToObject<List<EmailLog>>();   
}
```

The JSON is parsed and only the desired key is extracted.

This assumes that value of `"total_count"` was not needed so only extracts the `items` value.

If the entire object is wanted then defining a root object and deserializing to that would be the easier approach, as demonstrated in [@Isma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187050/5233410)

**UPDATE**:

Based on discussion you indicated that the service is currently returning

```
"Mailgun Magnificent API"
```

which would match the invalid character exception being thrown trying to parse **M**, as it is clearly not well formatted JSON.

After reviewing the Mailgun documentation it looks like the URL you are using will only work in a browser and was not meant to be used the `HttpClient` class.

The [documentation explains](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication) that the request should be made using BASIC authorization

For example.

```
var myMailgunDomain = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.xxxxx.ca/";            
var client = new HttpClient() {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(myMailgunDomain)
};
var apiKey = "api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var parameter = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKey));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
    .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", parameter);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("log");
//...
```

Comment: This answer was more correct for my situation, thank you

Comment: Still getting same error message, going to try the other solution

Comment: @dave317 recheck the JSON string being returned, looking over the exception message it appears the string is starting with an invalid charater at the start of the string (position 0), which would make the string invalid JSON, hence the error. Confirm that the JSON being returned is valid JSON.

Comment: How would I check that? If I enter my Uri and Query in a Browser it brings up the JSON I pasted into my question above..

Comment: @dave317 can you show more of the code that is making the request for the data? I assume you are using a `HttpClient` and that  `response` is a `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: I just did that.  If you need my API key to assist me with this (and don't mind doing so), I can send it to you via DM

Comment: @dave317 ok Let's trouble shoot. You say that the JSON shown in the question is from the browser. Debug your code and check  what is the data returned from `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`. set a break point and check that value.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help Nkosi, i have never dealt with Breakpoints so I will need to do some google research on how to do that.  Probably will not be able ot work on this until later this evening.  Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @dave317 No problem, glad to help. Ping me, I'll check it when I get a chance. Happy coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174471/discussion-between-dave317-and-nkosi).

Comment: Thank you for the update!  Finally got it to work.  Strange that my code did not work.  The API must be very fussy about formatting/ creating the Uri and using brackets in the Base Uri VS the Request.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is trying to get a list of `EmailLog` objects directly because they are enclosed within the "items" element of your json response.

You can solve it by using a wrapper class, for example:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "total_count")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public List<EmailLog> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And then you don't need to use a list to deserialize:

```
var flogs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);
```